# Angular JS HTTP Post not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

When I use local computer using XAMPP my code is working fine but when I upload my webpage to the my InMotion Server it is not working.

Error shows

> [object Object]

My Code:

```
$http.post("/aa/bb/public_html/php/checker.php",{"data1": val, "data2": para})
        .then(function(response) {
            if(para == "namedis"){
                $scope.dsnamedis = response.data;
            }else if(para == "namedise"){
                $scope.dsnamedise = response.data;
            }else if(para == "namein"){
                $scope.dsnamein = response.data;
            }else if(para == "namest"){
                $scope.dsnamest = response.data;
            }else if(para == "namemd"){
                $scope.dsnamemd = response.data;
            }else if(para == "namels"){
                $scope.dsnamels = response.data;
            }else if(para == "email"){
                $scope.dsemail = response.data;
            }else if(para == "pass"){
                $scope.dspass = response.data;
            }else if(para == "passc"){
                $scope.dspassc = response.data;
            }else if(para == "idno"){
                $scope.dsidno = response.data;
            }else if(para == "phoneno"){
                $scope.dsphoneno = response.data;
            }else{


            }


        }, function(error,status) {

        $scope.fstatus = { message: error, status: status};
        console.log(status); 
        });
```

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
$gc = file_get_contents("php://input");
$datas = json_decode($gc, true);
$cc = $datas['data1'];
$dd = $datas['data2'];
if($dd == "namedis"){
echo "<span class='text-danger'> <i class='fa fa-times-circle-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>aaaa.</span>";
}elseif($dd == "namedise"){

and so on
```

How to solve this problem.

When I remove the .htacess file it is working fine. How to work it with .htacess file.

```
RewriteBase /

DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex disabled

RewriteEngine on

# prevent direct access to PHP files
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404,L]

# rewrite requests for a directory to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0/index.php [L]

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument   403 /errors/403error.php

ErrorDocument   404 /errors/404error.php
```

Comment: you can't access anything above `public_html` directory on most hosts. That is the web root directory. Try changing url to `"/php/checker.php"`

Comment: yeah i already use like this but not working

Comment: In your edit you are still trying to access directories above `public_html` and the `public_html` directory iteself. You can't do that. You can only access what is inside `public_html`

Comment: I also tried $http.post("aa.lk/php/checker.php";,{"data1": val, "data2": para}) like this it is also not woking

Comment: what is `aa.lk`? Is that a directory inside `public_html` and inside that is a directory `php`? Show us the directory structure **inside** public_html

Comment: no. normally  Inmotion root directory is public_html. Inside that folder have php folder. But when I use links inside php I want to put like this /home/mywebsite/public_html/php/ otherwise not working

Comment: You are confusing php using paths to include files with web paths accessible by browser. They are not the same thing

Comment: $http.post("/php/checker.php",{"data1": val, "data2": para}) I also tied like this but it is not working

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. What is status? What do you see in response body? Also check server error logs

Comment: error shows like this [object Object]

Comment: you must be using an alert on that...look at it in console where you can actually see the properties and values

Answer (score 1):

> $http.post("/../.../public_html/php/checker.php"

This is an absolutely wrong way to make a request.

Read [the basics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) please and welcome to the beautiful world of web developement!

Comment: I am sorry to tell you $http.post("/../.../public_html/php/checker.php" this is not same this has somethng link this $http.post("/aaa/bb/public_html/php/checker.php"

Comment: I also tried $http.post("http://www.aa.lk/php/checker.php",{"data1": val, "data2": para}) like this it is also not woking

Comment: There should be something like $http.post("http://example.com/checker.php"
depending on where is your site's ROOT directory

Comment: yeah it is same as above comment code but not working

Comment: Then open a Chrome Dev Tools (or any other depending on browser) and check if your request has reached the server. There should be 404 error if your url is wrong, or 200 status if request was successful. Also check response for server-side errors.

Comment: I found the error. when i delete .htacess file it is working fine. this is my .htacess file contents.